# Concat values from a column and make another column

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am working with Spark SQL, and doing some SQL operations on a Hive Table.
My table is like this:
```

```
ID COST CODE
1  100  AB1
5  200  BC3
1  400  FD3
6  600  HJ2
1  900  432
3  800  DS2
2  500  JT4
```

```

I want to create another table out of this, which would have the total cost and top 5 CODES in a chain in another column like this.

```

```
ID  TOTAL_COST  CODE  CODE_CHAIN
1   1400        432   432, FD3, AB1
```

```

Total Cost is easy but, how to concat the values from the CODE column and form another column.

I have tried collect_set function but, the values cannot be limited and also are not properly sorted, probably due to distributed processing.

Any SQL logic is possible?

EDIT:

I need the data sorted, so I get  top 5 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `slice`, `sort_array`, and `collect_list`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(
    sum("cost") as "total_cost", 
    slice(sort_array(collect_list(struct($"cost", $"code")), false), 1, 5)("code") as "codes")
```

In Spark 2.3 you'll have to replace `slice` with manual indexing of the sorted array

```
val sorted = sort_array(collect_list(struct($"cost", $"code")), false)("code")
val codes = array((0 until 5).map(i => sorted.getItem(i)): _*) as "codes"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use window function and with() table to filter on the first row_number. Check this out:

```
scala> val df = Seq((1,100,"AB1"),(5,200,"BC3"),(1,400,"FD3"),(6,600,"HJ2"),(1,900,"432"),(3,800,"DS2"),(2,500,"JT4")).toDF("ID","COST","CODE")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ID: int, COST: int ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show()
+---+----+----+
| ID|COST|CODE|
+---+----+----+
|  1| 100| AB1|
|  5| 200| BC3|
|  1| 400| FD3|
|  6| 600| HJ2|
|  1| 900| 432|
|  3| 800| DS2|
|  2| 500| JT4|
+---+----+----+


scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("course")

scala> spark.sql(""" with tab1(select id,cost,code,collect_list(code) over(partition by id order by cost desc rows between current row and 5 following ) cc, row_number() over(partition by id order by cost desc) rc,sum(cost) over(partition by id order by cost desc rows between current row and 5 following) total from course) select id, total, cc from tab1 where rc=1 """).show(false)
+---+-----+---------------+
|id |total|cc             |
+---+-----+---------------+
|1  |1400 |[432, FD3, AB1]|
|6  |600  |[HJ2]          |
|3  |800  |[DS2]          |
|5  |200  |[BC3]          |
|2  |500  |[JT4]          |
+---+-----+---------------+


scala>
```

Comment: This works fine. But, the data jumps from here to there in another run.
For example: 
[432, FD3, AB1]

becomes
[FD3, 432, AB1]

Is this because of distributed processing.Any idea how to deal with it?

Comment: that can change only when you have tie on cost values.. example 200,200 like that

Comment: Right! I see it. Thanks :)